# Not all cron jobs runs properly

Tags: php, debian, cron

I have the big strange trouble - yesterday i have 3 my cron jobs working properly. But today - only 2. And there is a problem - i have all cron jobs using php like this:
`/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/username/data/www/site.tld/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`
But today i have mystic things:
1. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` showing cron is running properly on this site
2. shell command `/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/username/data/www/site.tld/cron.php` working properly - script are working
3. BUT! I used ISPManager Lite as server-manager, and run cron job from it - i get `Exited with error code - 255`. Other cron jobs runs from ISPManager Lite normally.
4. Of course, when i apply script in shell by hands - it works; if cron do this work - nothing happened.

Any suggestions, please??

System: Debian, ISPManager Lite, PHP5.2.6-1+lenny8, Apache2.0

UPD1: Server Administrator email me:
`resource        held     maxheld   barrier   limit      failcnt

kmemsize        13355322 33677498  33554432  36909875   2644082

privvmpages     58616    127740    114688    126157     24442`
Is it right, or my provider want more money?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redirect of standard output and error so you can see what's going wrong. Set `MAILTO=somerealaddress@example.org` at the top of your crontab if you don't get mail on the local system.

Comment: Can i ask you a favor? Can you wrote an example of Top_of_my_crontab? Where is it?

Comment: The crontab file where you configured that script to run... at the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set it manually from the shell.

crontab -e

/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/username/data/www/site.tld/cron.php

Comment: It is set already! Using `crontab -l` show my cron job. And when i rewrite it, cron didn`t correctly working too.

Comment: Try to run directly from shell once, with copy paste and no redirection of the output so that u can see that on console and check if there is any errors.

Comment: I`ve just made it. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` return this stroke: `Nov 25 01:10:01 SERVER /USR/SBIN/CRON[5448]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/username/data/www/site.tld/cron.php)`, but nothing really happened with DB (script must did it). Script runned from shell directly working correctly.